# UE5 crashing when starting

Tags: crash, new-operator, unreal-engine5

I just began learning UE5, but when I installed it and started it up for the first time, I got this error, how do I fix it?[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dk2EC.png)

I tried to just reinstall it but that didn't work and I can't think of anything else to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue, top of the line graphics card and RAM but getting the D3DDEBUG crash. I've gone on YouTube and attempted to fix this and the only thing that actually has worked for me is going into project settings and turning off Shader Model 6 (SM6). This allows my project to run without error but doesn't give me the full ability of UE5.